# Airflow - Graph / Tree View Of Previous Dynamic Dag Runs

Tags: airflow

I have a dynamic dag that creates different tasks (and flows) on each run.

The issue is that the Graph or Tree View always shows only the last run flow (and tasks).

So if I want to see the logs from let's say 2 executions ago, I have to go to the log files themselves (because its tasks are not present at all in the last run).

Is there a way to see the actual dag run (that is not based on last dynamic dag run) view somewhere - so that I can see tasks that do not exist anymore?

Thanks.